# Referring with some

Tags: word-choice

'Many images, including some of the attack on social workers, have been shot up close, making you feel involved in what they show.'

With 'some'  I mean some images. Is this clear or would you read it as some of the attack?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I did read that part one more time, I believe. Perhaps you could replace *some* with *those*, or write *some depicting/portraying/etc. the attack* instead of *some of the attack*. I think the wording's natural enough, and it quite possibly might have been just my fault reading too quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that 'some of the attack' stands too well on it's own and that makes it confusing.

I would say it's correct, but, I would rework the sentence so that it has the 'some' closer to 'images' e.g. 'some of the images of A were B, making you C.